# Error Handling on mongoimport

Tags: json, bash, mongodb, shell, mongoimport

I have a directory of roughly 45,000 json files. The total size is around 12.8 GB currently. This is website data from kissmetrics and its structure is [detailed here](http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/data/#what-is-the-format-of-the-data).

The data:
Each file is multiple json documents separated by a newline
It will be updated every 12 hours with new additional files

I want to import this data to mongoDB using mongoimport. I've tried this shell script to make the process easier:

```
for filename in revisions/*;

do

echo $filename
mongoimport --host <HOSTNAME>:<PORT> --db <DBNAME> --collection <COLLECTIONNAME> \
    --ssl --sslCAFile ~/mongodb.pem --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> \
    --authenticationDatabase admin $filename

done
```

This will have errors

```
2016-06-18T00:31:10.781+0000    using 1 decoding workers
2016-06-18T00:31:10.781+0000    using 1 insert workers
2016-06-18T00:31:10.781+0000    filesize: 113 bytes
2016-06-18T00:31:10.781+0000    using fields:
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    connected to: <HOSTNAME>:<PORT>
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    ns: <DBNAME>.<COLLECTION>
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    connected to node type: standalone
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
2016-06-18T00:31:10.822+0000    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2016-06-18T00:31:10.824+0000    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'l' looking for beginning of value
2016-06-18T00:31:10.824+0000    imported 0 documents
```

I will potentially run into this error, and from my inspection is not due to malformed data.

The error may happen hours into the import.

**Can I parse the error in mongoimport to retry the same document?** I don't know if the error will have this same form, so I'm not sure if I can try to handle it in bash. **Can I keep track of progress in bash and restart if terminated early?** Any suggestions on importing large data of this size or handling the error in shell?

Answer (score 1):

Typically a given command will return error codes when it fails (and the are hopefully documented on the `man` page for the command).

So if you want to do something hacky and just retry once,

```bash
cmd="mongoimport --foo --bar..."
$cmd
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "retrying..."
  $cmd
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    "failed again.  Sadness."
    exit
  fi
fi
```

Or if you really need what `mongoimport` outputs, capture it like this

```
results=`mongoimport --foo --bar...`
```

Now the variable `$results` will contain what was returned on `stdout`.  Might have to redirect `stderr` as well.

Comment: Use --stopOnError option to get the status code after mongoimport command has completed